# Refreshing Tree View in MongoVUE

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

In SQL Server and MySQL, you are able to refresh the hierarchy view of the database in the left-hand pane.  Can you do the same with MongoVUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the tree node to refresh in the left-hand panel and then click the `Refresh` button in the top right of the panel.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just right click the node you want to refresh and choose it from the popup menu.